# Quadratic extension $L/K$ is inseparable $\iff$ $char(K)=2$ and $\exists \alpha \in L$ \ $K$ with $\alpha^2 \in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

For $char(K)=2$ and some $\alpha \in L$ \ $K, \alpha^2\in K$ show that $L/K$ is quadratic, i.e. $[L:K] = 2$

I know it has something to do with the characteristics being equal to 2, but no idea where to start. Any hints?

EDIT:

The exercise I am trying to solve is:

Quadratic extension $L/K$ is inseparable $\iff$ $char(K)=2$ and $\exists \alpha \in L$ \ $K$ with $\alpha^2 \in K$

I think that I have a good solution for $\Rightarrow$, but for $\Leftarrow$ I manage to show $L/K$ is inseparable by the fact that $f = Irr(\alpha,K) = x^2 - \alpha^2$. There exists then a $g \in K[x], g = x - \alpha^2$. It holds that $f(x) = g(x^2)$ and because $char(K)=2$, it holds that $f$ is inseparable and thus $\alpha$ is inseparable. Which also proves $L/K$ is inseparable. But I don't know how to show it is quadratic, hence my question.

Comment: Somehow I suspect that the question should have been related to [this FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098276/let-lk-2-and-char-k-neq-2-show-that-l-k-is-a-simple-2-radical-extension?rq=1), and that there is something confused, but I may be mistaken. Simon, could you state the question again, a bit more detailed?

Comment: Ok now, I think.